# alert only file names selected from file input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this ajax call which checks if the selected file names of a multiple file input already exist in the database. and if they do, it alerts a message telling them. The problem is I can only get it to alert all the file names from the result loop. how can I edit it so that it only alerts the file names that were selected? Thanks.

```
var file = $('#file')[0];
$.get('existing-filenames.php', function(data){

   for (var i=0; i<file.files.length; i++) {
   var fname = file.files[i].name;

   if(~data.indexOf(fname)){ 
    // only alert selected file names
    alert("these files already exist:" + data); 
     return false;
    }
  }
},'json');
```

and in existing-filenames.php

```
$allfiles = $db->query("SELECT filename FROM files WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'");

$result = [];
while( $files = $allfiles ->fetch_assoc() ){
       $result[] = $files['filename'];
   }
       echo json_encode($result);
```

and html

```
<input name = "file[]" type = "file" id = "file" multiple />
```

Comment: I don't think your going to get anything from `var file = $('#file')[0];`  You should alert fname to check what it is.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, add more jQuery:

```
$('#file').on('change', function () {
    var self = this;
    $.get('existing-filenames.php', function (data) {
        $.each(self.files, function () {
            if (data.indexOf(this.name) != -1) {
                alert("these files already exist:" + this.name);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be alerting fname instead of data?

Here's how you do it:

```
myfiles = '';

for(var i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++)
{
     if(~data.indexOf(fname)){
          myfiles += fname;
     }
}

if(myfiles !== ''){
     alert("these files already exist:" + myfiles);
}
```

Does that make sense? We keep a running string of the files that we've added, and we alert them all at the end. You could add commas between them, or spaces, or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

alert `fname` instead of `data` and remove `return false;`

```
   if(~data.indexOf(fname)){ 
     // only alert selected file names
     alert("these files already exist:" + fname); 
    }
```

Comment: but this will only alert 1 filename there might have been multiple files selected that both are in the database